# org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Encrypted message contains a signed message not literal data

Tags: java, security, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

I have an encrypted csv type file that I created via [pgptool](https://pgptool.org/) and I want to decrypt this file in my java application using the [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) library, but I get the error "Encrypted message contains a signed message not literal data", what could be the reason for this?

When I debug my code, it enters the following if block "if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList)" but I don't understand why it enters, I expect the type of my message to be "PGPLiteralData"?

This is my pgp message I want to decrypt:

> -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
>
> Version: Keybase OpenPGP v2.0.76
>
> Comment: https://keybase.io/crypto
>
> wYwDLAyGLP4eR3cBA/43VKG4RcqQCFaJcy60+B0C/ZuyDtbgyYvU2DMA5h0F1wMY
> 2zT+XtBMp7ZFt8M9KuPiGzFKR/DvAtWgaTYKpJWqjlQmZVeRkEDauDnEn7ZIICBK
> rWgalv/pN8Odl6WHfGZ0qL4aPNDGfUiqkNmMhTZSj1oaMOgv/GZHItNX4iBGMtLA
> 9wGcGj9iyMK8LfV/wX2n0Bz7h21O64MO+ob7VhQej96xjpAS1NIU55o6ipI0YDam
> 8mxVZJPMMAAIVaXuzRygmMkhWyWX2tfTqSm1A9f6t7hvomw9SAdgc0Lvb7Qd8/aT
> 1UaGAIZgSX9AiWa+WuTVDO3uFszH2VD/ZhjhDDUhJFZNjdfikkQv1FMF6ysRuGkd
> 2PpzezqU4f5uwhgxK/qMRAtJEVkNtZfcRDQdSM/miuOF6ooQRtD7LJT7JzsFIAMW
> +nEkht9g6RT0LHbQMylGl5aJY9pAskmWbPO3mlL56XAWj7Owi2b8RKIrb92UoteS JkbzRoLBGzvyLaJ9RoE9i/bZqMxTvWVJrFQWEnAms0r/ZGP8gC8i4NtPROH6RdTk
> XJrUrg+zy+sizUemMcCiHQ0O+tVlV2biQ67DpAQJa6GHcvrryHygjPzaIPg+lJkS
> XHyCwafXedPY5eWhi1jdYyGOgvRZRrztTEb5QprDHBvONQv1cZcS55/DkC/iNT1y
> IHFoqgj20TsYcI47RR1Ejm6ey1DzZ2dOlHJrcdkhJOHYM7VVLDHR1cPBXDewP8t+
>
> 72Irzz2+SSE=
>
> =+pp7
>
> -----END PGP MESSAGE-----

These are my decryption codes:

> I.

```
    public String decrypt(String encryptedData) {
    try {
        PgpDecryptionUtil pgpDecryptionUtil = new PgpDecryptionUtil(PRIVATE_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptedData.getBytes();
        byte[] decryptedBytes = pgpDecryptionUtil.decrypt(encryptedBytes);
        return new String(decryptedBytes, Charset.defaultCharset());
    } catch (IOException | PGPException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

> II.

```
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes) throws PGPException, IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream encryptedIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(encryptedBytes);
    ByteArrayOutputStream clearOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    decrypt(encryptedIn, clearOut);
    return clearOut.toByteArray();
}
```

> III.

```
    public void decrypt(InputStream encryptedIn, OutputStream clearOut)
        throws PGPException, IOException {
    // Removing armour and returning the underlying binary encrypted stream
    encryptedIn = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(encryptedIn);
    JcaPGPObjectFactory pgpObjectFactory = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(encryptedIn);

    Object obj = pgpObjectFactory.nextObject();
    //The first object might be a marker packet
    PGPEncryptedDataList pgpEncryptedDataList = (obj instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList)
            ? (PGPEncryptedDataList) obj : (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpObjectFactory.nextObject();

    PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivateKey = null;
    PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData publicKeyEncryptedData = null;

    Iterator<PGPEncryptedData> encryptedDataItr = pgpEncryptedDataList.getEncryptedDataObjects();
    while (pgpPrivateKey == null && encryptedDataItr.hasNext()) {
        publicKeyEncryptedData = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData) encryptedDataItr.next();
        pgpPrivateKey = findSecretKey(publicKeyEncryptedData.getKeyID());
    }

    if (Objects.isNull(publicKeyEncryptedData)) {
        throw new PGPException("Could not generate PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData object");
    }

    if (pgpPrivateKey == null) {
        throw new PGPException("Could Not Extract private key");
    }
    CommonUtils.decrypt(clearOut, pgpPrivateKey, publicKeyEncryptedData);
}
```

> IV.

```
    public static void decrypt(OutputStream clearOut, PGPPrivateKey pgpPrivateKey, PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData publicKeyEncryptedData) throws IOException, PGPException {
    PublicKeyDataDecryptorFactory decryptorFactory = new JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder()
            .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).build(pgpPrivateKey);
    InputStream decryptedCompressedIn = publicKeyEncryptedData.getDataStream(decryptorFactory);

    JcaPGPObjectFactory decCompObjFac = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(decryptedCompressedIn);
    PGPCompressedData pgpCompressedData = (PGPCompressedData) decCompObjFac.nextObject();

    InputStream compressedDataStream = new BufferedInputStream(pgpCompressedData.getDataStream());
    JcaPGPObjectFactory pgpCompObjFac = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(compressedDataStream);

    Object message = pgpCompObjFac.nextObject();

    if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
        PGPLiteralData pgpLiteralData = (PGPLiteralData) message;
        InputStream decDataStream = pgpLiteralData.getInputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(decDataStream, clearOut);
        clearOut.close();
    } else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList) {
        throw new PGPException("Encrypted message contains a signed message not literal data");
    } else {
        throw new PGPException("Message is not a simple encrypted file - Type Unknown");
    }
    // Performing Integrity check
    if (publicKeyEncryptedData.isIntegrityProtected()) {
        if (!publicKeyEncryptedData.verify()) {
            throw new PGPException("Message failed integrity check");
        }
    }
}
```